# matching single and double quotes in grep using -E

Tags: command-line, text-processing, grep, regex

For practicing how ***grep*** works in Ubuntu terminal, I made one **`.txt`** file:

```
'"..asdf_-_-..34'""'"'"
jd8m***ns'''_**''x;';nn*?/...;  
++..++
./,/;]_+))(+_)((*+_":|.<"{}+_)09+_):}.}-0_)
```

I wanted to match asjacent single and double quotes using `grep -E -e '\'+\"+' -e '\"+\'+'`
But it is not giving desired output.
Can anyone please help me with the same?

Comment: Single-quotes remove all special meaning, "backslash" is no exception, which means the second single-quote will still be in effect, so everything after will basically be unquoted. The third single-quote will obviously be a mismatch. For this to work, you need to do something like `'one'\''two'` or in short `''\'''` (as @steeldrive pointed out, using double-quote will be a lot simpler in this case).

Comment: Hey, it is still not working. It is asking for some kind of input in newline with `>` sign.

Comment: Yeah, this `"'+\"+"` regex works. But I don't know why this `'"+\'+'` or this `'\'+\"+'` or this `'\"+\'+'` or this `"\'+\"+"`. So I needed all the line which can have adjacent single and double quotes in any combination. Also, the one which works is supposed to give the combinations of quotes where `'` comes before `"`, but not `"` and then `'`.

Comment: Let's take two examples ```echo '\'``` and ```echo 'test'\''s'```, you can't escape a single quote inside a single quote because backslash ```\``` loses its special meaning. So in bash, you have to concat multiple strings together for example, ```'"+\'+'``` should be ```'"+'  \'  '+'``` or ```'"+'  "'"  '+'``` and as concated ```'"+'\''+'```

Comment: and because the `+` sign does not have any meaning in bash you can get away with `\"+\'+` or `\'+\"+` if the order is important.

Comment: @bac0n Thanks a lot. Your comments gave a clear picture.